# Haskell - Signature and Type error

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm having some trouble with function signature and types. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to make a list with every number between 1 and 999 that can be divided by every numeral of it's own number. For example the number 280 can be in that list because 2+8+0=10 and 280/10 = 28 ... On the other hand 123 can't because 1+2+3=6 and 123/6=20,5. When the final operation gives you a number with decimal it will never be in that list.

Here's my code:

```
let inaHelper x = (floor(x)`mod`10)+ (floor(x/10)`mod`10)+(floor(x/100)`mod`10)
```

This first part will only do the sum of every numeral of a number.
And this part works...

Here's the final part:

```
let ina = [x | x <- [1..999] , x `mod` (inaHelper x) == 0   ]
```

This final part should do the list and the verification if it could be on the list or not. But it's give this error:

```
No instance for (Integral t0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it


...
```

Comment: `it` does not appear in the code you've shown. What else did you type into the GHCi prompt?

Comment: After inaHelper I typed inaHelper 280 to test the program and it apear the number 10. So I thought It was OK.

Comment: Then I wrote the code for ina as I said earlier. And next simple wrote ina in the prompt

Comment: Btw `inaHelper` can be written `sum . fmap (read . pure) . show` and will work no matter how many digits your numbers have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ina = [x | x <- [1..999] , x `mod` (inaHelper x) == 0   ]
```

What is the type of `x`? `Integer`? `Int`? `Word`? The code above is very generic, and will work on any integral type. If we try to print its type we
get something like this

```
> :t ina
ina :: (Integral t, ...) => [t]
```

meaning that the result is a list of any type `t` we want, provided `t` is an integral type (and a few other constraints).

When we ask GHCi to print the result, GHCi needs to choose the type of `x`, but can not decide unambiguously. This is what the error message states.

Try specifying a type when you print the result. E.g.

```
> ina :: [Int]
```

This will make GHCi choose the type `t` to be `Int`, removing the ambiguity.

Comment: I thought It could be something similar to that. I tried but it gives other error:                                                                                                      No instance for (Integral int1) arising from a use of ‘ina’
    Possible fix:
      add (Integral int1) to the context of
        an expression type signature: [int1]
    In the expression: ina :: [int]
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = ina :: [int]

Comment: @JoãoSantos You need `Int`, with an uppercase `I`.

Comment: ina :: [Int]

<interactive>:57:1:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘ina’
    In the expression: ina :: [Int]
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = ina :: [Int]

Comment: @JoãoSantos The issue now is that you are using `floor` and `/` which are for floating point types, only, and `mod` which is integral, only. Remove `floor` and use `div` for integer division e.g. ``5 `div` 2 `` is `2`. You might have other issues in your code, but slowly you'll be able to fix them all.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Your suggestion made it work. I now understand the problem of using floor in this situation.

Comment: @JoãoSantos As a general suggestion, it greatly helps if one annotates each global definition with an explicit type. Otherwise, sometimes, GHC will infer some unintended general type which does make the code compile so far, but will generate problems when later on one makes use of that definition. Detecting problems early makes them easier to fix.